# Vim in Windows CMD: Prevent Windows from writing to Registry HKCU\Console colors from Vim colorscheme?

Tags: windows, vim, command-line, cmd, registry

I don't really understand why it happens, but sometimes when I use Vim in the Windows Command Prompt the color which is used for background in Vim's color-scheme gets written to the HKCU\Console in the Registry as the default color for the Command Prompt itself.

Why is this and can I do something to prevent it from happening?